# Python issue editing tkinter canvas items in a 2darray

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, multidimensional-array

I'm using a raspberry pi as a communication front end for more complex devices. I'm coding it in python, and including a gui to display the information going through it.

My issue involves a grid of canvas text items of size 4x4, as referenced by a 2d array `dataText[][]`. I am editing the items using `itemconfigure()` to update the displayed data.

The issue: when i update `dataText[y][x]`, no matter the numbers, it updates the item at position (3,x) instead.

Demonstrative code:

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import Style

#gui class (tkinter loop)
class UI(Frame):
    #data value field
    dataText = [[0]*4]*4

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.parent = parent

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        #sets up the main window
        self.parent.title("Power Converter Controller")
        self.style = Style()
        self.style.theme_use("default")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

        #configures padding along columns and rows
        for i in range(4):
            self.columnconfigure(i, pad=3, weight=1)
        for i in range(7):
            self.rowconfigure(i, pad=3, weight=1)

        #creates a canvas at the top of the window. The canvas is used for
        #displaying data
        self.display = Canvas(self, width=600, height=170)
        self.display.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=4, rowspan=4)

        #draws canvas items that can be updated
        self.dynamicCanvasItems(self.display)

    def dynamicCanvasItems(self, canvas):

        #initializes the grid text handles
        for i in range(4):
            for j in range(4):
                self.dataText[i][j] = canvas.create_text(75*(j+1),25*(i+1),text = data[i][j], font=("Helvetica",20))

        for i in range(4):
            for j in range(4):
                self.display.itemconfigure(self.dataText[i][j], text=5)

def main():

    global root
    global data

    #initialize 2d data array
    data = [[x]*4 for x in xrange(4)]

    #initialize the ui loop
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("600x300+600+300")
    ui = UI(root)

    #enter the ui loop
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The whole program is rather large, so I've cut out irrelevant portions. I made sure that the redacted portions had no effect on the issue (by disabling them and checking if the problem changed).

in the `dynamicCanvasItems()` method, the widgets are set up correctly. If you disable the second dual for-loop, it displays this:

```
0    0    0    0
1    1    1    1
2    2    2    2
3    3    3    3
```

So the second dual for-loop should overwrite all of the widgets with 5. However, this happens:

```
0    0    0    0
1    1    1    1
2    2    2    2
5    5    5    5
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your initialization code is creating a list of lists, where each sublist is a reference to the same object. You don't have a list of four different sublists, you have a list of four references to the same list.

To prove this, add the following right after you initialize `dataText`:

```
print [id(x) for x in dataText]
```

You'll see that all four lists have the exact same internal id, meaning they all reference the exact same list.

Compare what happens when you change your initialization code to this:

```
dataText = [
    [0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0]
    ]
```

In the above, you are explicitly creating four unique lists, each with four unique values.